# Why in Spring I am not allowed to annotate a final class with @Configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, spring-annotations

I am studying for the Spring Core certification and I have some doubts related to the answer of this question founded on the study material stuff.

> **Why are you not allowed to annotate a final class with @Configuration**

My reasoning is the following one for substantiate this assertion:

Consider the following configuration class:

```
@Bean
public AccountRepository accountRepository() {
    return new JdbcAccountRepository(); 
}

@Bean
public TransferService transferService() {
    TransferServiceImpl service = new TransferServiceImpl();
    service.setAccountRepository(accountRepository());
    return service;
}

@Bean
public AccountService accountService() {
    return new AccountServiceImpl(accountRepository());
}
```

At first look this situation could appear strange because the first method (**accountRepository()**) instantiates an **JdbcAccountRepository** object as a bean having **id=AccountRepository** that, following the Spring default behavior, is a **singleton**

The second and the third method call **twice more time** the **accountRepository()** method that should instantiate twice more **JdbcAccountRepository** objects and this is not possibile because it is singleton !!!

So, to solve this situation Spring use the **Inheritance-based Proxies** strategy that expect to **create a child class of my configuration class** (the one annoted by **@Configuration**) and it is does:

- **For each bean, an instance is cached in the child class**
- **Child class only calls super at first instantiation**

So the child class is the entry point because the following behavior is implemented by this child class:

public class AppConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$ extends AppConfig {

```
public AccountRepository accountRepository() {
    // if bean is in the applicationContext
    // return bean
    // else call super.accountRepository() and store bean in context
}

public TransferService transferService() {
    // if bean is in the applicationContext, return bean
    // else call super.transferService() and store bean in context
}

.....................................................
.....................................................
.....................................................
}
```

So if I annotate a configuration class with **final** Spring can't have this behavior because in Java **a final class cannot be subclassed**

Is it correct?

Using the same reasoning can I also assert that in Spring **I can't have a final method annoted with @Bean annotation**?

Because, as shown in the previous example, I have that when at startup time is created the child class (the proxy) of my configuration class happens that **for each bean, an instance is cached in the child class** and if it is final it is not possible (but I am absolutly not sure about this assertion)

Am I missing something? Can you give me the exact explaination?

Tnx

Answer (score 12):

Spring creates dynamic proxies for classes annotated with `@Configuration` classes. Spring uses CGLIB to extend your class to create proxy. Hence, configuration classes cannot be final.

**Regarding `accountRepository()` being invoked twice:**

If you invoke `accountRepository()` method to create an instance, it is no more a Spring managed bean. Spring will not have any idea of the instances created in this manner. Hence, you will end up with multiple instances of `JdbcAccountRepository`

You can preserve the singleton behavior if you configure as below:

```
@Bean
public TransferService transferService(JdbcAccountRepository jdbcAcctRepo) {
    TransferServiceImpl service = new TransferServiceImpl();
    service.setAccountRepository(jdbcAcctRepo);
    return service;
}

@Bean
public AccountService accountService(JdbcAccountRepository jdbcAcctRepo) {
    return new AccountServiceImpl(jdbcAcctRepo);
}
```

Comment: Actually if the subclassing works correctly, you can call other bean methods (like accountRepository()). The proxy will then determine if it is necessary to create a new bean instance or if one already existrs.

Comment: If the configuration class is not final, Spring can sub-class. And, related to the `accountRepository()` method invocation, Spring doesn't know what is happening inside the method. Spring cannot hook in a logic to check if the bean is already created, each time the `new` operator is used.

Comment: Even it's a bit late, but i just stumbled again over this answer: Of course Spring cannot see what happens in the accountRepository() method. But the Spring proxy will intercept all calls to the accountRepository() method itself, and checks, if there is already a bean of that type and name defined in the current application context. If this is the case, the proxy returns the bean (and doesn't execute the method), if not, the real method is called and the returned bean is stored in the application context. That's why it's safe to call bean creation methods multiple times in a configuration bean

Comment: @dunni, you are absolutely right, @Mithun, Please refer java doc for `@Bean` annotation (methods in `@Configuration` annotated classes section of doc)